# Why isnt Angular 1.3.x available in code snippets?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Yes, I know I can just change `<script src=....` to 1.3.x, but I'm just wondering if there is a reason why 1.3.x is not in the dropdown. Its been out for a while and is stable.

I would ask same question applies to 1.4.x, but I presume the answer is that its not stable yet.

Comment: Do you use a package manager like npm or bower?

Comment: @Rimian why would it matter for the purpose of stack snippets?

Comment: Not sure. I'll look into it so I know!

Comment: then you would say it should have : Vanilla js ,backbone js ,mustache js,handlebar js . Its not possible to include all JS libraries

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Vanilla js is automatically included; backbone I might argue for also; mustache and handlebar are used not used nearly as much. Most importantly though is that you already have a drop down for angular. Might as well put the latest version on it.

Comment: What about making a crowd-sourced list of libraries (where multiple votes are required to add a library) and being able to select them just like tags by typing the first few characters ?

Comment: @AndréDaniel That seems way more complicated than it needs to be. Plus there is still the "add external library button".

Comment: @DavidGrinberg if we want to move away from JSFiddle we need to provide the same easy to use features, including their very long collection of libraries. And we shouldn't just provide the same, we should do better, and my idea seems better than a dropdown like on JSfiddle.

Comment: "Vanilla js is automatically included" … umm ok

Comment: … I can't tell if you're trolling or just don't have a clue about javascript.

Comment: Yes. Vanilla means "without a framework included"… so you can't really include it. Unless you include [this joke](http://vanilla-js.com).

Comment: @bjb568 Or another way of saying that is that its automatically included everywhere... either way, there is no point to this.